# How to select all edges between two edges in edge ring mode in python?

Tags: python, selection-tools

Is there a way to select all the edges between 2 selected edges in ring mode (not in edge loop) in python?

[image: iE5v.png]

Comment: I can't really help you on the python side but you can select these edges with the pick shortest path method (when you hold control) and by checking face stepping in the popup menu

Comment: If you do it manually in Scripting view and check 'Face Stepping' on the bottom-left 'Pick Shortest Path' dialog you get : "bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_pick(edge_mode='SELECT', use_face_step=True, use_fill=False, index=655)" which might help.